# Display Lists and different reactions to mouse movement in JOGL

Tags: opengl, jogl, displaylist

I recently started to work with an API in our Java application environment which uses JOGL (makes OpenGL commands accessible in Java) to create a 3D environment within our application (so I am pretty new to OpenGL).

This API uses display lists to group and speed up the commands to display a geometric component. So far, in the display method, first all the changes to the scene made by the mouse are applied (zoom, rotation, translation), then the current display list is called. 
The API provides a variety of scene elements (surfaces, light, transformations) which are put into a tree-like structure. This structure determines the order in which these scene elements will be "executed" later. This execution of the scene tree is than put into a display list. This works as intended.

What I want to add now is a small coordinate system as a representation of the component's current orientation. This would be a new scene element to be added to the scene tree.
This coordinate system should obviously be influenced by rotations done with the mouse, but it should not be scaled or translated to other places.

My problem is: As the mouse movements are applied outside of the execution of the scene tree, I don't know how to apply **only the rotation** to **only a certain scene element** of the tree. I can't just revert the mouse movement in the corresponding part of the display list (in my understanding) because that would mean the display list would have to take the parameter of the mouse position's changes. But I can't work with parameters in display lists as their state is determined once and then only executed in this state (correct?). I can't just reset the projection matrix as I would lose the rotation state.

I hope my problem is understandable. Is there a way to do this with display lists or do I might have to replace the display lists in this API with an alternative? They don't seem to be recommended anyway.

Comment: Don't use Display Lists they are deprecated, as well as `glBegin`, `glEnd`, `glTranslate`, `glRotate`, `glScale`, `glMatrixMode`, `glLoadIdentity`, etc. If you're going to make an API, then don't use all the deprecated methods.

Comment: Furthermore, do not use display lists unless you fully understand how they work. Improperly managed, they cause a lot of state leaks that can be really hard to track down. You are free to implement your own construct that behaves like a display list if you want however; you could even do it smarter than OpenGL and implement systems to prevent state changes that occur within 1 display list from affecting things outside of the display list.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman In fact, I didn't "use" display lists, I use an API written by s.o. else who doesn't work here anymore and just discovered that this is implemented with display lists. Sounds like I have to change that.

Comment: Its definitely worth looking into what newer versions of OpenGL have to offer.